# How to import or decode .mesh file with unity (or python if its not possible)

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, 3d, binaryfiles, mesh

I have some .mesh binary 3d files that a program creates and I want to decode them, edit them than encode them again, is this possible? If so, how.

EDIT: file example: pastebin.com/5BpWgTkY

Thanks, FB

Comment: How did you create the file? Do you understand the format of it? What sort of editing are you hoping to do?

Comment: I do not fully Understand the format of it, I want to change basically most every aspect of it, color, vertices, etc